# ReactJs - Correct way to handle state/props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components:

1. Main (Containing a table component and a button)
2. Modal component
3. Form component

The workflow goes like this: A button in main "New X" calls the Modal which opens up with the Form component inside it.

In the above, I have kept the form input as a state of Form (To be able to validate etc.)

Now, I need a new workflow: A double click in the table in Main should open the modal and the form but with the row data entered in the form (To be able to edit the data)

To reuse as much code as possible I wanted to use the same Modal/Form components but pass the row data as props through Modal into component.

As for now, the row data is a state of Main, passed as props to Modal and finally passed as props to Form which then sets it to state.

My question is: Is that the correct way to handle it? In theory I could then have two components having a different state of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems the correct way to handle it. React developer's team recommend to keep the [state lifted up as much as possible](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

For sure you can handle it in different ways but you'll end quite always to lift the state as up as you can.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that the correct way to handle it?

Yes.

> In theory I could then have two components having a different state of the data.

No, not really. The Form is the only one that manages the state.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I see your point with Form being the only one managing it but App has the state as well? I mean if you change the state of Form the initial state of App won't change => Different data in the states - Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah sure I understand. I'll try to rephrase: A change in the Table Component (inside App) sets the state of App => Send state as props to Modal => Pass props on to Form and init state as props. This way we have both state in App and in Form - Make sense?

Comment: @alex5207 ah okay, but both states still represented two different things: App stores the selected cell (and its inital content), Form stores the current changes